# Google Maps JavaScript API Heatmap Layer- Limit of data points that can be displayed on the map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to the Google Maps JavaScript API and I'm applying a heatmap layer on google maps, similarly to the example in the maps heatmap documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

I'm loading a lot of datapoints for the heatmap but **only a limited amount are displaying.**

I don't see any issues with the data; when I cut the dataset into smaller chunks the heatmap appears in different places each time I load the map.

But I can see in the usage documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) that there's a limit of 2,500 requests per day, and I don't know what the definition of **one request** is in this scenario.

Is it that when the map loads with `initMap()`, the entire `HeatmapLayer` being applied is considered *one single request*?

Or is it that, when I'm creating a heatmap with 4,000 datapoints, each call to `new google.maps.LatLng()` for each datapoint is considered *4,000 separate requests*?

Comment: The heatmap layer is calculated in your browser, doesn't have anything to do with API limits.

Comment: _when the map loads with initMap(), the entire HeatmapLayer being applied is considered one single request_ this is true. Below answer displays the usage details

Comment: Only a request to load the map counts as a request. There is no limit on the number of points you can plot `new google.maps.LatLng()` definitely does not count as a request. Things such as geocoding, places autcomplete, directions etc count as a request. Is there any chance you are using any of those? There is a bit more detail about usage here: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits are you able to set up a jsfiddle or similar with an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the example in the docs, I created an example that creates 10,000 points to plot on a heatmap, with no issue. So it can't be any kind of rate limit. There must be something else at play. This example does not even have an API key, so on the free plan.

[Ten thousand heatmap point demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w098d14e/7/)

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

        var map, heatmap;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
    });

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: getPoints(),
      map: map
    });
  }

  function getPoints() {

    var lotsOfMarkers = [];

    for( var i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {

       var random = new google.maps.LatLng( (Math.random()*(85*2)-85), (Math.random()*(180*2)-180) );

        lotsOfMarkers.push(random);
    }

    return lotsOfMarkers;
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: You can experiment with the numbers too. I tried 30k points, confined to within a smaller area - no issue

Comment: Hey Paul thanks for the effort! I've accepted this as the answer. My code was similar to yours and still didn't work for me, however my issue was finally resolved by adding the `maxIntensity` property to the map, and setting it to a low number (1 or 2).

Comment: @AnonyMouse glad you got it sorted. Does that mean that your points were always plotting, but you couldn't see any difference as the intensity was too great?

Comment: I guess so? 1) the points were only displaying on some parts of the map and 2) when I would zoom in on high density areas the points would fade away (similar to how they do in your jsfiddle). As soon as I used `maxIntensity` 1) the full set of points were displaying all over the map, and 2) they remain visible even when I zoom in all the way. I'm not familiar enough the Google Maps JavaScript API to know what happened there.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) has these following quotas if you check your developer console.

[image]

It means that you can load your map 25,000 times per day and the user can only make 1 request per second.  While the unlimited here means that the maps can load simultaneosly.

So every time you call your API key like [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap), it count as a 1 load per day.

Note: The Daily quotas reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT)